# Move child nodes with dynamic "SCNPhysicsBody" through parent node animation

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, physics-engine, scnnode

I'm doing a game which is basically a pacman in 3D using SceneKit.

[image]

The nodes tree is defined as follow :

`rootNode <-- GameRotationNode <-- GameNode`

All nodes (blueboxes, colored balls, dots, light blue and purple floor tiles) are children of GameNode.

All nodes except colored balls have either static or no physicsbody. Colored balls have dynamic physics body.

I'm applying a constant rotation through the Y axis to the whole game board with the following code

```
let Sequence = SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, 
                                                          y: degreesToRadians(Degres: 90), 
                                                          z: 0, 
                                                   duration: 5))
GameRotationNode.runAction(Sequence)
```

The issue is that the colored balls are not rotating like the rest of the board. Everything else is rotating fine but the nodes with the dynamic physicsbody are not
rotating. If I change their physicsbody to static or none, then they rotate also.

But the colored balls (and later some other nodes) need to have a dynamic physicsbody to handle movements, contacts and collisions.

Is this a limitation of physicsbody management of SceneKit?

Or are there other ways to achieve what I want?

Comment: try use `force` instead of `actions` on dynamic nodes

`yourNode.physicsBody?.applyForce(SCNVector3(0, degreesToRadians(Degres: 90), 0), asImpulse: true)`